# how to add custom data/url in grafana for monitoring metrics

Tags: amazon-ec2, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, grafana-api

i want to add custom data/url in grafana for monitoring the metrics.
how can do this ?
in url have a data in the from of table,i want to use that data in grafana and get the graph for it.
is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what's your question but if u want to add data to grafana, u need to add datasource in grafana in your web interface. See https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/ for more details.

Comment: i want a add custom data source(http://tools.admaxim.com/clustermonitoring/build/rtbfrnewvk) in grafana to monitor the table in the from graph.my question how to add it as a data source.i seen the list of data source cloudwatch,elasticsearch ect but i want to add custom data source which link mention above.it possible or not if yes then how its ?

Comment: Okay, so this is possible with plugins.Check here : https://grafana.com/docs/plugins/developing/datasources/  (how to developp a plugin) or maybe you can find existing plugins here : https://grafana.com/plugins?type=datasource .
 What are you using for your database ?

Comment: i m use influxdb for database and telegraf for visualization the graphs.

Comment: Ok , you know that Grafana is just a tool for monitoring, so if u want to use it, u have to build new dashboard with panels inside it .Grafana will replace your actual pagewith new grah or tables. here : https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/influxdb/
If you'll install influxdb as datasource in grafana you'll be able to customize all data from you're database on grafana and no more on your page.